# DataTable clear search filter and reload takes two clicks

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using DataTables and have some javascript to clear the search filter and redraw the table. The search text clears but the table is not updating unless I click twice.
Here is my code:

`<input type="text" class="form-control id="table-search">`

```
  $('#clear-filter').on('click', function(){
    $('#table-search').val('');
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
  });
```

Comment: I think, You should used to textbox change event

Comment: I do have this connected to the search filter also ie.                                
        `$('#table-search').on('input', function() {                                                    
              var _this = this;
          if (_this.value !== '') {
            table.search($(_this).val()).draw();
          }
          else {
           table.search('').draw();      });`

Answer (score 1):

remove the "columns()" part...

```
table.search('').draw();
```

Comment: I tried this and still not working, it seems to not be picking up that the table search value has been cleared, only when I do a setTimeout, which is not ideal in my case so it must be a synchronization issue with the datatable server call...anyone else experience these server side datatable timing issues?

Comment: ahh yes... it could be a race situation.. in which case using a setTimeout with timeout of 0 should force it to be executed after the fact...

Comment: also it could be that your click handler is not getting called since the filter is created after events are registered especially if you are using an ajax data source.

Try using $('body').on('click','#clear-filter',function(){...});

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem while trying to clear search filter added in individual columns.

I was using `table.search('').columns().search('').draw();`

Changing the code to `table.columns().search( '' ).draw();` resolved the issue for me.

Refresh the browser few times and clear cache